# why i got this error in angularjs function(param1,param2)

Tags: angularjs, function

This is my code :

```
ng-click="create({{item.variants[0].id}},{{item.variants[0].title}})"
```

and the errors :

`Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token 'Title' is unexpected, expecting [)] at column 26 of the expression [create(743922959,Default Title)] starting at [Title)].`

what should i suppose to do in order to make clean function without errors but still preserve parameter that i put into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just remove interpolation there. Just do:-

```
  ng-click="create(item.variants[0].id, item.variants[0].title)"
```

or just pass in variants and access id, and title from the object passed to your handler:-

```
 ng-click="create(item.variants[0])"
```

Because when doing the way you did it will create the expression as `create(743922959,Default Title)` which is invalid in javascript. Because the second argument which is supposed to be a string `Default Title` is passed in as token.